# I am working on project using nextjs and strapi. I am getting error from one of my component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

Error is TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'menu')[fact is everything about that component is right still i get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSQTC.png)
I am working on the neighborhood page and there I am not even using this component, this pic that I shared is of an index file that displays the neighborhood page, the left and right sides are the continuous part.
[this pic is of all returned components of neighborhood page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7d4A.png)

[there is a withLayout function which is used in index file i.e neighborhood page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jymC.png)

```
const Layout: FC<PropsWithChildren<LayoutProps>> = ({
  children,
  header,
  footer,
  footerContent,
  language
}) => {
  return (
    <main
      className={`${headingFont.variable} ${bodyFont.variable} relative flex min-h-screen flex-col overflow-x-hidden font-sans`}
    >
      <NavBar
        menu={header.menu}
        ctaTitle={header.ctaTitle}
        homeUrl={header.homeUrl}
        language={language}
      />
      {children}
      <Footer
        columnOne={footer.columnOne}
        columnTwo={footer.columnTwo}
        content={footerContent}
      />
    </main>
  );
};

//this is LayoutProps
export type LayoutProps = {
  header: FetchHeaderResult;
  footer: FetchFooterResult;
  footerContent: FooterContentList[];
  language: string;
};



export const withLayout: GetServerSideProps<LayoutProps> = async ({
  query,
  req: { url }
}) => {
  const language = getLanguage({ query, url });
  const [header, footer, footerContent] = await Promise.all([
    await strapi.fetchHeader({
      lang: language || "id",
      province: "jakarta",
    }),
    await strapi.fetchFooter({
      lang: language || "id",
      province: "jakarta",
    }),
    await strapi.fetchFooterContent({
      lang: language || "id",
      province: "jakarta",
    }),
  ]);

  return {
    props: {
      header,
      footer,
      footerContent,
      language
    },
  };
};
```

please someone help.

i was integrating the backend with frontend to display data on website.
i expecting some other error this error was coming before too, my senior help me he said it is due to ipV6 wifi router settings but even after running it on ip address it s giving some other error. note: senior solution worked but after i did drastic changes it is showing same thing again.

Comment: We need some more context to help you solve this issue. LayoutProps interface, header interface, where you are using the Layout component, and where are you getting the data that you are injecting into layout props

Comment: okay I have edited the question kindly check again.

Comment: There are two possibilities here. Either strapi.fetchHeader() promise is not returning the header object with a menu prop on it or maybe you are not getting a response at all. I would console.log() the header after you receive the response from promise.all(). You can also look in the network tab of chrome devtools or w.e. browser you are using. Also maybe your type for header does not have the prop menu on it. Check all those first